# The element is present in html page yet bs4 could not find element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get text from a `ul` tag in the floorplan section but I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`. This is the website link: https://housing.com/in/buy/projects/page/271622-pride-atlantic-by-pride-builders-llp-in-lohegaon

And this is my code:

```
html_v = soup.find('div', class_="css-7dw83l").find("ul")


for b in html_v.find_all("li"):
    configuration = b.text
    print(configuration)
    b.click()
    #ar = soup.find('ul',class_="header-container css-n0tp0a")
    #for aa in ar.find_all("li"):
     #   aa.click()
    price = soup.find('div',class_="css-6yyk38").text
        
    rate = soup.find('div',"css-lo3e7n").text
    rate = rate.split(" ")
    rate = rate[0]
    rate = rate[1:]
    print(rate)
    print(price)
    print(configuration)
```

And this is the section I want to extract:
the floor plan section where area and bhk are mentioned

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVMd4.png)

Comment: That section of the page is dynamically constructed by JS. What exactly your desired out be?

Comment: I want to extract configuration, area and price

Answer (score -1):

The error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'` is suggesting that your variable `soup` has a value of `None`.  You need to fix the instantiation of bs4